# Pulling String and Integer Data From Text File

Tags: c++

I am a TOTAL beginner to C++ and I'm having some issues with a project.
I have a text file with a list of employee names and the amount of hours they worked. In the file, both the names and hours are occasionally repeating, and recorded for each day. Some names show up more frequently than others.

**For example:** 
John Smith 8 
John Smith 7 
John Smith 8 
Jane Jones 9 
Jane Jones 8 
Maxwell Ko 7 
Maxwell Ko 8 
Maxwell Ko 8 
Maxwell Ko 8 
(Numbers represent the hours worked)

My code looks something like this so far, but I'm having issues separating the data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    const double tax = 0.12;
    const double rate = 18.00;
    
    
    string firstName, lastName;
    int hours;
    
    
    ifstream inputFile;
    string filename = "/Users/luie/Desktop/employeehours.txt";
    
    
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    cin >> filename;
    
    inputFile.open(filename);
    string name = firstName + " " + lastName;
    
    if(inputFile)
    {
        while(inputFile >> firstName >> lastName >> hours)
        {

            if(firstName == "John" && lastName == "Smith")
            {
                while(firstName == "John" && lastName == "Smith")
                {
                    int JohnHours = hours *= hours;
                    cout << "Total Hours Worked: " << JohnHours << endl;
                }
                if 
            }
            
            
            cout << "Employee Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << " \n Hours Worked: " << hours << endl;
        }
       
            
       inputFile.close();
    }
        
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file. /n";
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

How would I go about pulling the string information (names of employees) and separating it from the integer information (hours worked)? Furthermore, I would like to add up the total number of hours worked for each person to create an "Overall hours worked:" output for each person. I will have to use the total hours worked for a gross & net pay calculator where the pay is $18 per hour and the tax is %12. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read input from the text file until/after a specific location \[C++\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638243/how-to-read-input-from-the-text-file-until-after-a-specific-location-c)

Answer (score 1):

**A cstdio Approach**

Well, there are a number of ways to approach splitting the line into the `name` and `hours` worked. The trivial way is to use the C `fscanf()` (fragile for direct read) or read the entire line into a `std:string` and then use `.c_str()` with `sscanf()` to separate the line into `name` and `hours` (a variance in input line format does not cause a failure to read all subsequent lines). With either `fscanf()` or `sscanf()` you could use the format string `" %[^0-9]%lf"` to parse the line into `name` and a `double` value for `hours` (you will need to trim trailing whitespace from `name`). You could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

#define NAMSZ 128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as 1st argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open filename provided as 1st argument */
    
    if (!f.is_open()) { /* validate file is open for reading */
        std::cerr << "file open failed: " << argv[1] << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::string tmp {};
    
    while (getline (f, tmp)) {      /* read each line into tmp */
        char name[NAMSZ] = "";      /* buffer to hold name */
        double hours = 0.;          /* double to hold hours */
        
        /* separate name & hours from line (protect array bound w/field-width) */
        if (sscanf(tmp.c_str(), " %127[^0-9]%lf", name, &hours) == 2)
            std::cout << std::left << std::setw(32) << name << hours << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example input in the file `dat/hoursworked.txt`, you would receive the following:

```
$ ./bin/workerhours_cstdio dat/hoursworked.txt
John Smith                      8
John Smith                      7
John Smith                      8
Jane Jones                      9
Jane Jones                      8
Maxwell Ko                      7
Maxwell Ko                      8
Maxwell Ko                      8
Maxwell Ko                      8
```

But now you are left with how to collect all the like names and then sum the hours worked.

(**note:** mixing `csdtio` functions and `iostream` is perfectly okay, and in a number of circumstances will provide improved performance over other methods. See additional notes on mixed use at [C++ iostreams: Unexpected but legal multithreaded behaviour](https://berthub.eu/articles/posts/iostreams-unexpected/))

**Mapping Total Hours Worked per-name**

When you think about coordinating a unique collection of items, your first thought should be to a [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Both provide a way of associating unique collections of objects based on a unique `key`. (in this case your `name`). The `unordered_map` doesn't hold the objects in any sorted order while `map` sorts the objects based on the sort function you provide (or a default, e.g [std::greater](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

In the simple case you can just create a map between `<std::string, double>` and then use the `.find()` member function to determine if the `name` already exists in the mapping, and if so, simply add the hours from the current line to the existing mapping, if not, add the new `name`, `hours` pair as a new element.

To complete your operation, you simply need to trim any remaining whitespace from the name (not done above) and use a `map` (or `unordered_map`) to create unique pairs of `name/hours` values. Simple additions are all that is required:

```
#include <map>
...
    std::map<std::string, double> workers {}; /* map of workers */
    ...
        /* separate name & hours from line (protect array bound w/field-width) */
        if (sscanf(tmp.c_str(), " %127[^0-9]%lf", name, &hours) == 2) {
            tmp = name;                         /* re-use tmp to make std::string */
            while (isspace(tmp.back()))         /* while trailing whitespace remains */
                tmp.pop_back();                 /* trim from end of sting */
            
            auto srch = workers.find(tmp);      /* search for name in map */
            if (srch != workers.end())          /* if name already in map */
                srch->second += hours;          /* add to hours */
            else    /* name not found */
                workers[tmp] = hours;           /* add new name to map */
        }
```

So above, after separating the initial `name` and `hours` strings, the `std::string tmp` is re-used to create a `std::string` from `name` and then `isspace(tmp.back())` is used to check if the last character is whitespace, and if so `tmp.pop_back()` is used to remove it.

With with the `std::map workers`, a search is performed to see if the name in `tmp` already exists, if it does, the hours are simply added to the existing hours (you use `workers->first` to refer to the `key` (name) and `workers->second` to refer to the mapped value (`hours`) when using the `srch` iterator). If the name doesn't exist, the new mapping is added.

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>

#define NAMSZ 128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as 1st argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open filename provided as 1st argument */
    
    if (!f.is_open()) { /* validate file is open for reading */
        std::cerr << "file open failed: " << argv[1] << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::string tmp {};
    std::map<std::string, double> workers {}; /* map of workers */
    
    while (getline (f, tmp)) {      /* read each line into tmp */
        char name[NAMSZ] = "";      /* buffer to hold name */
        double hours = 0.;          /* double to hold hours */
        
        /* separate name & hours from line (protect array bound w/field-width) */
        if (sscanf(tmp.c_str(), " %127[^0-9]%lf", name, &hours) == 2) {
            tmp = name;                         /* re-use tmp to make std::string */
            while (isspace(tmp.back()))         /* while trailing whitespace remains */
                tmp.pop_back();                 /* trim from end of sting */
            
            auto srch = workers.find(tmp);      /* search for name in map */
            if (srch != workers.end())          /* if name already in map */
                srch->second += hours;          /* add to hours */
            else    /* name not found */
                workers[tmp] = hours;           /* add new name to map */
        }
    }

    for (const auto& w : workers)               /* output results */
            std::cout << std::left << std::setw(32) << w.first << w.second << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/workerhours_cstdio_map dat/hoursworked.txt
Jane Jones                      17
John Smith                      23
Maxwell Ko                      31
```

If using the `unordered_map`, output similar to the following would be expected:

```
$ ./bin/workerhours_cstdio_umap dat/hoursworked.txt
Maxwell Ko                      31
John Smith                      23
Jane Jones                      17
```

That is probably one of the easier ways to approach the separation of `name` and `hours` and to coordinate the sum of the hours.

**Using the std::string Member Functions to Separate name and hours**

Of course it is fine to use `std::string` member functions like `.find_first_of()` and `.substr()` to handle the separation as well. (your compiler will need to support at least `-std=c++11`) That approach would look similar to:

```
    std::string name;
    double hours;
    ...
        const char *digits = "0123456789";
        std::string line {};
        while (getline (f, line)) {                             /* read line */
            size_t hoursbegin = line.find_first_of(digits);     /* find 1st [0-9] */
            if (hoursbegin != std::string::npos) {              /* valdiate found */
                std::string tmp = line.substr(0, hoursbegin);   /* get name */
                while (isspace(tmp.back()))                     /* remove trailing */
                    tmp.pop_back();                             /* .. spaces */
                name = tmp;                                     /* assign to name */
                hours = stod(line.substr(hoursbegin));          /* assign to hours */
            }
        }
```

Both are equally fine and both will handle lines like:

```
John J. Doe, III, M.D.  10.8
```

instead of simple first-name, last-name, hours lines.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Please have the integrity to leave a comment if you are going to downvote a correct answer. It is truly sad we can't treat each other better than this.

Comment: Thank you. It just blows my mind how shallow some people can be -- but then again, it is no different than in society in general.... All we can do is provide a positive example.